# Compiling string and returning it as a vector

Tags: c++, string, stl, stringstream

My server gets some requests, compiles response and sends it back. Sometimes response is a file, sometimes it’s HTML. So I define response in the following way:

```
class ResponseData
{

public:
    bool operator== (const ResponseData & param) const { return id == param.id; }

public:
    RequestIdType id;
    RequestType type;
    std::vector<char> data;
};
```

When I compile HTML response I use `std::stringstream`.

```
std::vector<char> RequestHandler::createResponse( const RequestData * request ) const
{
    std::stringstream buffer;

    std::vector<char> result;
    result.assign( RESPONSE_HEADER, RESPONSE_HEADER + strlen( RESPONSE_HEADER ) );

    buffer << "<tr>";


    for( auto param : request->paramsMap )
    {
        buffer << "<tr><td>" << param.first << "</td><td>" << param.second << "</td></tr>\n";
    }

    buffer << "<\tr>";

    DEBUG_LOG_F << buffer.str();

    std::string str = buffer.str();

    result.insert( result.end(), str.begin(), str.end() );
    result.insert( result.end(), RESPONSE_FOOTER, RESPONSE_FOOTER + strlen( RESPONSE_FOOTER ) );


    return result;
}
```

It seems to me that copying `buffer` to string to append it then to vector is not good idea. How can I do it more effectively?

Comment: I would suggest following optimizations. 1. Reserve the space in result beforehand for all the contents. 2. Get the streambuf instance from the buffer and then use its sgetn function to directly populate the result vector

Comment: Are you intending to have results with two deep `<tr>`?

Comment: @NishantSingh, seems like you missed couple of lines

Comment: @Caleth, thanks. Sure, no. But the main question is about effective copying stringstream to vector

Comment: @Yura srry I have updated the comment

Comment: @NishantSingh, perhaps that's the thing I asked. I'll try. Thanks

Comment: I will suggest use stringstream for everything as suggested by @Caleth and Reserve enough space in result and use streambuf instance for copying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `std::istreambuf_iterator` to copy characters directly from a `stringstream` to a vector, like this:

```
std::vector<char> sstreamToVector(std::stringstream& src)
{
    // make sure that "get" position is at the beginning and "put" is at the end of the stream
    src.seekg(0);
    src.seekp(0, std::ios::end);

    std::vector<char> dst;
    dst.reserve(src.tellp());
    std::copy(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(src),
              std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
              std::back_inserter(dst));
    return dst;
}
```

`str.tellp()` returns number of characters written to the stream (`p` stands for "put area"), so it can be used to allocate enough space in the buffer.

Comment: I would probably seek put to end and get to start, first, just to be safe, but otherwise 

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit good point, that (+maybe restoring them at the end) should be done when putting this in a separate function

Comment: Ooh restoring is a good idea. Some people would say that the cursor's state from outside the function should be abided by, and should be at the end after all the bytes are "consumed". but since we never really consume anything from a stringstream (at least not destructively), it doesn't matter too much as long as you document your choice.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that I understand you to be trying to avoid is the movement of `char`s between containers. It's not too hard to dump everything in `result` directly in this simple case:

```
auto result = accumulate(cbegin(request->paramsMap), cend(request->paramsMap), vector<char>{ '<', 't', 'r', '>', '<', '/', 't', 'r', '>' }, [](auto& init, const auto& i) {
    const char start[] = { '<', 't', 'r', '>', '<', 't', 'd', '>' };
    const char middle[] = { '<', '/', 't', 'd', '>', '<', 't', 'd', '>' };
    const char finish[] = { '<', '/', 't', 'd', '>', '<', '/', 't', 'r', '>' };

    init.insert(prev(cend(init), 5U), cbegin(start), cend(start));
    init.insert(prev(cend(init), 5U), i.first, next(i.first, strlen(i.first)));
    init.insert(prev(cend(init), 5U), cbegin(middle), cend(middle));
    init.insert(prev(cend(init), 5U), i.second, next(i.second, strlen(i.second)));
    init.insert(prev(cend(init), 5U), cbegin(finish), cend(finsh));
    return init;
} );

copy(cbegin(result), cend(result), ostream_iterator<char>{ DEBUG_LOG_F });
result.insert(cbegin(result), RESPONSE_HEADER, next(RESPONSE_HEADER, strlen(RESPONSE_HEADER)));
result.insert(cend(result), RESPONSE_FOOTER, next(RESPONSE_FOOTER, strlen(RESPONSE_FOOTER)));
return result;
```

Comment: How would the compiler prevent that here? (Hint: it won't!)

Comment: Your XML slashes are backwards and you didn't escape the erroneous resulting backslashes.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I had hoped that the compiler would recognize the construction of `result` here and move the contents of the OP's `buffer`, `RESPONSE_HEADER`, and `RESPONSE_FOOTER`... but even typing that out I'm way too optimistic... I'll edit.

Comment: Well I meant your claim about optimisation of the original code, but that too!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yeah really, `accumulate` is really doing a copy internally anyway right now. [P0616R0](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/p0616r0.pdf) should fix that in C++20 though...

Answer (score -1):

Just use the `stringstream` for everything. [joe_chip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52948829/2610810) demonstrates how to copy directly from the `stringstream`.

```
std::stringstream buffer;

buffer << RESPONSE_HEADER;

for( auto param : request->paramsMap )
{
    buffer << "<tr><td>" << param.first << "</td><td>" << param.second << "</td></tr>\n";
    DEBUG_LOG_F << "<tr><td>" << param.first << "</td><td>" << param.second << "</td></tr>\n";
}

buffer << RESPONSE_FOOTER;

return sstreamToVector(buffer);
```

Comment: @NishantSingh. Don't you think that `std::string str = buffer.str();` will slow down the program? If I do so, I instantiate memory once again only to get data from `stringstream`. It seems for me unnecessary

Comment: @Yura yes. but this is easier to understand

Comment: just don't do the string conversion, after populating the stringstream, get the streambuf instance and then use its sgetn function to populate the result vector. Anyways solution provided by joe_chip seems to doing the same thing, so it should be equally efficient

Comment: @Caleth, agree. But I think writing in C++ we should be focused on effectiveness. At least I try to learn approaches. And that was the question. Anyway thanks for ideas

Comment: You're still copying one more time than needed, which is what the question is trying to avoid (and the OP is right to do so).

Comment: Please take a look at the code:

 int main()
 {
  std::stringstream ss;
  ss << "test" << " ";

  std::stringbuf buffer;

  ss.get( buffer );
  char sentence[] = "[buf]";
  buffer.sputn( sentence, sizeof( sentence ) - 1 );

  ss << "[ss]";

  std::cout << "ss: " << ss.str() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "buf: " << buffer.str();

  return 0;
 }
 
Its output is 
 ss: test
 buf: test [buf]

This means that `stringstream` memory was copied to `stringbuf` memory. And this memory allocaiton is redundant.

Comment: @Yura: That's because you made a new buffer. The trick is to just copy straight out of the original one. Joe showed you how.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, sure. I've made a test of what Nishant Singh wrote

Comment: @Yura Nishant said to get the streambuf instance, not create a new one. You're doing extra things on top of what was proposed, and the extra things are where the inefficiency lies.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, agree